# Changes in biblatex-sbl and References to Arabic Literature

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, arabic

I want to include some minor changes into the sbl-style:

1. When I make a reference to a journal article, the sbl-style has this style:

> Jürgen Winkler, „Hi: Zwei“,St7,2 (2016): 9–33.

How can I change the double points to a comma, such as:

> Jürgen Winkler, „Hi: Zwei“,St7,2 (2016), 9–33.

2. An article in an edited volume will be shown as:

> Winkler, Jürgen. „Hallo Welt“. Seiten 10–35 in History.Herausgegeben von Jaap Baum und Werner Winkler. Hamburg, 2003.

How can I create this format:

> Winkler, Jürgen. „Hallo Welt“, in: Baum, Jaap/ Winkler, Werner (Hgg.): History, Hamburg 2003, 10–35.

3. An Arabic book within an Arabic series has this format:

> Kirk Son, Hrsg., ARABIC BOOKTITLE,2 Bde., ARABIC SERIESTITLE 3 (Beirut, 1995).

I am wondering why the volumes ("2 Bde.") were placed before the title of the series? How can I fix this?

Here is my example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{Winkler.2003,
 author = {Winkler, Jürgen},
title={Hallo Welt},
shorttitle = {Hallo},
 editor = {Baum, Jaap and Winkler, Werner},
 year = {2003},
 maintitle = {History},
 location = {Hamburg},
 pages={10--35},
}

@book{Son.1975,
 editor = {Son, Kirk},
 title = {\textarabic{رسائلن، تعريب}},
series = {\textarabic{عظماء ات}},
 number = {3},
 volumes = {2},
 date = {1975},
 location = {Beirut},
}

@article{Winkler:2016,
author = {Winkler, Jürgen},
title = {Hi},
subtitle = {Zwei},
shorttitle = {Hi},
journaltitle = {storia},
shortjournal = {St},
volume = {7,2},
date = {2016},
pages = {9--33},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage[variant=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Simplified Arabic}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

genannt\footnote{Vgl.: \cite{Winkler:2016}.} Dies gilt nicht.\footnote{Vgl: \cite{Winkler.2003}.} Oder doch?\footnote{\cite{Son.1975}.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that you have a better chance of getting an answer quickly if you ask only about one issue per question. That way you don't discourage people who know only part of the solution from writing an answer. Your question is also more relevant to other people and more generally applicable. See  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. It would make a lot of sense to split this question into three.

Comment: The `biblatex-sbl` style is designed to conform closely to the requirements of the SBL Handbook of Style and isn't always easy to adjust. I'll have a look at your questions later today when I get a moment. As for your third question, the reason that `volumes` comes before `series` is because this is specified in §6.1.1 of the handbook. What would you like to have happen? (Note that there can be confusion in terminology. `volumes` refers to the number of volumes in the *book*, not the total number of books in the *series*.)

Comment: Question 1 is straight forward and can be achieved by adjusting the `issue+date` macro. But question 2, is tricky. This will involve a substantial change to the `incollection` drivers which are quite complicated. Changes may have unintended consequences...

Comment: It would also be helpful if you can specify what you want both in notes and in the bibliography, since these are quite difference for `incollection` entry types.

Comment: Instead of `\footnote{Vgl.: \cite{Winkler:2016}.}` You can write `\footcite[Vgl.:][]{Winkler:2016}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, question 3 is nonsense. I have still some troubles with question 1 (I tried: \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{% 
  \printfield{issue}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{date}% 
  \newunit}), but I did not know where is the mistake?

Comment: my remark to question 1 belongs to the bibliography; in the notes, the mentioned macro worked.

Comment: I know that question 2 is complicated, but this is the only big issue where the sbl-style does not fit for typical German bibliographies for historians. I want the changes in notes and bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started.

Please be very careful with this. I've tried to think of some issues. But I have not changed how the translator is printed for the edited volumes and have only provided a simplistic implementation for printing the editor. The `incollection` drivers could maybe be simplified if you don't need to more obscure features of `biblatex-sbl`.

Some other notes:

- I *strongly* recommend you use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`. Language variants are not well supported with `polyglossia` and `biblatex`. Search this cite for many questions on this issue.
- I also switched to using `\autocite` rather than `\footnote{\cite}`.
- It's not super clear exactly what output you want for notes and bibliography, so I've just guessed. You can comment below if you can't figure out how to adjust things.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{Winkler.2003,
  author = {Winkler, Jürgen},
  title={Hallo Welt},
  shorttitle = {Hallo},
  editor = {Baum, Jaap and Winkler, Werner},
  year = {2003},
  maintitle = {History},
  location = {Hamburg},
  pages={10-35},
}

@book{Son.1975,
  editor = {Son, Kirk},
  title = {\textarabic{رسائلن، تعريب}},
  series = {\textarabic{عظماء ات}},
  number = {3},
  volumes = {2},
  date = {1975},
  location = {Beirut},
}

@article{Winkler:2016,
  author = {Winkler, Jürgen},
  title = {Hi},
  subtitle = {Zwei},
  shorttitle = {Hi},
  journaltitle = {storia},
  shortjournal = {St},
  volume = {7,2},
  date = {2016},
  pages = {9-33},
}

@mvlexicon{ED,
  editor = {George, Lucas},
  title = {Encyclopedic dictionary},
  shorttitle = {ED},
  location = {Rom},
  publisher = {Rom Press},
  date = {1911},
  shorthand = {ED}
}

@inlexicon{Brecht.2011,
  author = {Brecht, Jörg},
  title = {Art\adddot\space XYZ (ca\adddot\space 1451–1521) [Cath\adddot]},
  pages = {33-45},
  xref = {ED}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{#1}}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{issue+date}
  {\addcolon\space}
  {\addcomma\space}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibmacro{editor+others}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
  {\setunit{\addspace}
   \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibmacro{publisher+location+date}
  {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {\setunit*{\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibmacro{institution+location+date}
  {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {\setunit*{\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {}
  {}

\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \leavevmode\raise 0.6ex\hbox to 3em{\hrulefill}\addcolon\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[incollection]{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat[incollection]{finalnamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimFormat*{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  editors = {Hgg\adddot}
}

\makeatletter
\let\blx@saved@delimcontext\blx@delimcontext
\newcommand*{\savedelimcontext}{\let\blx@saved@delimcontext\blx@delimcontext}
\newcommand*{\restoredelimcontext}{\let\blx@delimcontext\blx@saved@delimcontext}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{bookeditor}{%
  \savedelimcontext
  \delimcontext{incollection}%
  \ifnameundef{bookeditor}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
       {}
       {\printnames[family-given]{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
        \clearname{editor}}}
    {\printnames[family-given]{bookeditor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
     \clearname{bookeditor}}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \restoredelimcontext}

\newbibmacro*{maineditor}{%
  \savedelimcontext
  \delimcontext{incollection}%
  \ifnameundef{maineditor}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
       {}
       {\printnames[family-given]{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
        \clearname{editor}}}
    {\printnames[family-given]{maineditor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
     \clearname{maineditor}}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \restoredelimcontext}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:incollection}{%
  \ifentrytype{seminarpaper}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{inentrytype}}%
  \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iftoggle{blx@usefullcite}
    {}
    {\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{in:}%
     \iffieldundef{booktitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
        \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
        \newunit}%
     \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
        \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{edition}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{note}%
     \usebibmacro{parens+publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{ebook}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{addendum}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{isbn}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \toggletrue{inentrytype}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \ifentrytype{classictext}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
     \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
     \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ebook}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\xpatchbibdriver{cite:article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\iflistundef{institution}
     {\usebibmacro{parens+publisher+location+date}}
     {\setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{institution+location+date}}}}
  {\iflistundef{institution}
     {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}
     {\setunit{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
genannt \autocite[Vgl.:][]{Winkler:2016}. Dies gilt nicht
\autocite[Vgl:][]{Winkler.2003}. Oder doch \autocite{Son.1975}? Filler text
\autocite{Brecht.2011}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks! There are some minor wishes: I want in the notes and in the bibliography:      1) instead of "Son, Kirk, Hg. ..." this: "Son, Kirk (Hrsg.): ..." 2) instead of "Winkler, Jürgen. "Hallo Welt". In: ..." this: "Winkler, Jürgen: "Hallo Welt", in: ..."

Comment: @user191310, can I just double check what strings you want for `editor` and `editors`? Should it always be "Hrsg." for singular and "Hgg." for plural? (Sorry, I don't know any German.)

Comment: @user191310, Ugh. Unfortunately, I didn't use `nametitledelim` to make it easy to customise the delimiter between the name and the title. (I'll change this in future releases). For now, every driver you use will have to be patched to place a colon between that name and the title.

Comment: you are right: "Hrsg." for singular and "Hgg." for plural.

Comment: @user191310, how's that now?

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect! In note 3, the location and date should not be in brackets and in the bibliography of an article in a collection, I did not want a point after the year, but a comma (e.g. Hamburg, 2003, 10-15). Last point: How can I ignore the comma between location and place completely (in bibliogr. and notes for incollection, books, articles, diss. ...)?

Comment: There is a problem when one of my lexicon-articles ended with a "[]", have a look at: @mvlexicon{ED,
editor = {George, Lucas},
title = {Encyclopedic dictionary},
shorttitle = {ED},
location = {Rom},
publisher = {Rom Press},
date = {1911},
shorthand = {ED}
}
@inlexicon{Brecht.2011,
author = {Brecht, Jörg},
title = {Art. XYZ (ca. 1451–1521) [Cath.]},
pages = {33--45},
xref = {ED}
} In notes and the reference should be: Brecht, Jörg: „Art. Bedjan, Paul. (1838–1920) [Chald.]“, ED. 33-45. => but the comma is missing in front of "ED"

Comment: @user191310, see my latest edits. The missing comma is because `biblatex` thinks this the dot at the end of "Cath." is a period and so doesn't add more punctuation after it. You should use `\adddot` instead to indicate that "Cath." is an abbreviation. You *are* going to have to further patch various drivers and macros. The relevant files are `sbl.cbx`, `sbl.bbx`, and `biblatex-sbl.def`. There should be enough examples in my answer to figure out what to to do, but if you need help it's best to ask another specific question with MWE.